# html - how to make a scroll with the width on auto?

Tags: css, html, width, scrollbar

I have a div with lots of content in it, and trying to set a width to be 100% of the parent element. This div also uses a padding, so I thought I should be setting the width to auto. 
But for some reason it always expands past the parent width. I even have overflow set to scroll.

What I want is the div to have a scroll bar (only horizontal), and its width to fit the parent width.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Have you tried `width: 100%; overflow-x: scroll`?

Comment: yes, but with this, the horizontal scroller didn't show (it was grayed out) and it still expanded past the parent width.

Answer (score 3):

**100% width of its parent, with padding:**

Given that the padding you mention is applied to the 100% wide element, the problem is within the [box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) that browsers use. If you apply 100% width and some padding, the element will get `width + padding` as its complete width, thus causing it to become too large. There are a few ways to solve this:

1. CSS3 introduces a new property called [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Box-sizing), by setting it to `border-box`, the padding will be added within the given width of the element, instead of adding to the width causing the element to become "to big". (Notice the lack of support by older browsers).
2. I believe it would be possible to use `left: 0; right: 0;` instead of using `width: 100%;`. In that case you can add padding, without the element becoming to wide.

*The second option in practice:*

```
<!-- The markup -->
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Child</div>
</div>​

/* The CSS */
.parent {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #666;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #888;
}
​
```

*Here is a working example of the second option: http://jsfiddle.net/mGLRD/*

**Horizontal scroll-bar:**

To get a horizontal scroll-bar, you will have to look in to the [`overflow-x`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/overflow-x) CSS-property. By setting it to `scroll`, you will see a disabled scrollbar when there is no content to scroll, so the scrollbar is always visible. Your other option is to set it to `auto`, where the scrollbar will become visible if needed (may vary between different browsers).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
div#content {
    width:auto;
    padding:20px;
    overflow-x:auto;
}
```

See my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HRRsU/3/

Comment: it didnt work with mine. The content in the div has a table with 1 row and lots of columns, each cell has a specified width and height.

Answer (score -1):

```
box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Comment: Please add details, why have you posted this, how it helps user to solve his problem!